# How to create two histograms on one plot with shared axis?

Tags: histogram, tableau-api

I tried to plot arrival delay and departure delay columns separately, **it's clear the distributions are different**.

I would like to show them on the same plot, but whenever I try to do so, **both plots became one identical shaped distribution** although I'm plotting two different columns! What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help in advance.

[image: different distributions]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need a Departure Delay (bin) field. You can create one by selecting Departure Delay in the data pane on the left sidebar and selecting Create bin.

Once you have that new field, you can place it on the Columns shelf next to the other bin field and just put SUM([Number of Records]) on the Rows shelf — getting rid of both CNT() fields.

That should let you see both histograms.

To answer your question about why your previous approach yielded the same chart, you were binning data in both cases by the Arrival delay.

The CNT([xxx]) fields are misleading. That just counts the number of records that have a non-null value in the [xxx] field. If [xxx] always has a value, its equivalent to SUM[Number of Records]). The bin field is what matters.